# GAE Endpoint Error: can not access a member of class with modifiers "private"

Tags: java, json, api, google-app-engine

I have a GAE API Endpoint that keeps giving me a 503 Error.  The API Endpoint does its job properly (processes/post data to the datastore), but once it comes to return the object, this error is thrown:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to instantiate standard
>   serializer
>   (oftypecom.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.NullSerializer):Classcom.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BasicSeriaiizerFactory
>   can not access a member of class
>   com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.NullSerializer
>   with modifiers "private"

The object which is being returned is an Extended object (*FacebookUser extends User*).  I thought it may have something to do with accessing the base class private variables, so I declared all private variables as protected; I still keep getting this error.

I have one other endpoint which returns a FacebookUser object and it works fine.  I interpret it as a GAE serialize cannot serialize the object on return; the data being returned is a lot of the same data being returned in the one working endpoint. The API Endpoint does its job properly, but once it comes to return the object and data, the above error is thrown.

Any input is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So I figured it out.

I had a function called getToken() in the FacebookUser class. This function was not a getter/setter for a private/protected variable; it was a function which processes incoming information into a token. It seems like the GAE Java APIs assumed getToken was a getter/setter for private variable called "token." Since there isn't a private variable called "token" it was throwing the error I saw. I figured it out when it threw an error for the getToken() function when I ran another function which didn't call the getToken() function.